# Axios sends POSITION instead of ID to the controller on delete

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, crud

Im new to vue js, I found it a bit confusing in some parts but here is the latest confusion I am facing.

for example, I want to delete a row with the id of 3 but its position in the list is 0, when hitting delete it returns error in the console:

```
DELETE http://simvuecore/api/contoh/0 404 (Not Found)
```

which means axios sends the `position` while the controller expect `id`even though `id` is actually not stated there.

for a refference, here are my codes:

`API routes`:

```php
Route::delete('/contoh/{contoh}', 'contohController@destroy');
```

`contohController`:

```php
public function destroy(contoh $contoh)
{
    $contoh->delete();
    return response('terhapus', 200);
}
```

`store.js`:

```js
state: {
    contoh: []

},
mutations: {
        deleteContoh(state, id) {
            const index = state.contoh.findIndex(item => item.id == id)
            state.contoh.splice(index, 1)
        }
},
actions: {
    deleteContoh(context, id) {
        axios.delete('api/contoh/' + id)
            .then(response => {
                context.commit('deleteContoh', id)
            })
    },
}
```

`contohItem.vue`:

```js
methods: {
        removeContoh(id) {
            this.$store.dispatch('deleteContoh', id)

        },
```

all CRUD operations work properly when using `POSTMAN` and when requested from vue, `delete` is the only one that doesn't work because of this `position` and `id` issue.

QUESTION:
how to tell axios to send `id` instead of `position` to the controller?

UPDATE:
Problem solved by following @andrey popov's answer.
I had this in `contohItem.vue`:

```
    <span @click="removeContoh(index)" class="remove-contoh">X</span>
```

and it works after i changed it to this:

```
    <span @click="removeContoh(id)" class="remove-contoh">X</span>
```

Comment: Show us where you call `removeContoh`? It should be somewhere in `contohItem.vue`. There you'll have the answer :)

Comment: yes, it's in `contohItem.vue`, here is the tag `<span @click="removeContoh(index)" class="remove-contoh">x</span>`. shoud i replace the `index` to `id`?

Comment: Well, your question is `how to tell axios to send id instead of position`, so I bet it would be better if you don't send `index` but the `id` :P Good luck!

Comment: i've changed it but still get the same errror

Comment: But what is the `url` now? Does it still contain `0` instead of the actual `id`?

Comment: @AndreyPopov your first answer was correct. solved by changing `index` to `id`. but how to accept your answer while it's in the comment section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code I can see you're passing `id` all the way along the functions and `deleteContoh` action actually sends that to the server. Which means the way you call `removeContoh` is the problem - you're passing not `id` but `index`, and therefore you should change that.

Good luck!

Comment: great.. this helped.